# LongListMultiSelector in databinded Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8, pivot

i work on an app, which has a pivot and each pivot item has a LongListMultiSelector. Both work with databinding. I want to work with the selected Items of the LongListMultiselector. I found this:

```
private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T :    DependencyObject
            {
                var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
                if (count == 0)
                    return null;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        return (T)child;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                        if (result != null)
                            return result;

                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
```

I edited it to this:

```
private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement, int ind) where T : DependencyObject
    {

        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                if (LonglistSelectorNumber == ind)
                {
                    LonglistSelectorNumber = 0;
                    return (T)child;
                }
                LonglistSelectorNumber++;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child, ind);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

But if i add more than 3 items to my List from my Pivot, my Method give me a null-Reference.

I need another way to find all LongListMultiSelector in my Pivot.

my pivot:

```
  <phone:Pivot x:Name="WorkoutPivot" Title="Workouts" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkoutList}" SelectionChanged="WorkoutPivot_SelectionChanged" >
        <phone:Pivot.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WorkoutNote;component/Assets/PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </phone:Pivot.Background>
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                ...
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector Margin="-5,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ExercizeList}" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" AllowDrop="False">
                    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,12" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
                           ...
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>

            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? At the top you say you want the SelectedItem of the LongListMultiSelector, you can accomplish this by listening to the SelectionChanged event of the LongListMultiSelector, or binding a property on your viewmodel to the LongListMultiSelector.SelectedItem property

Comment: I want to accomplish two things. 1. the IsSelectionEnabled property should change by an buttonclick. 2. After selection you can click the delete button and the selected items will be removed from my List. I have no problems with these things. I just want to know how to build up a List of my LongListMultiSelectors in the OnNavigatedTo Method to access them.